# 'Type mismatch' error when reading ArrayList item in excel vb. Why?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple code that reads unique records from a sheet and it works fine. It returns an 2D array. When I try to assign elements into String variables, it shows an Type Mismatch error.

```
    Dim brd As String
    Dim unt As String
    
    Set SMT_DOE_Unique_Board_Unit = New ArrayList
    SMT_DOE_Unique_Board_Unit = WorksheetFunction.Unique(ws2_smt_doe.Range("B5:C" & brdRows))
For Each board_unit In SMT_DOE_Unique_Board_Unit
    brd = board_unit(1, 1)
    unt = board_unit(1, 2)
next
```

I get the 'Type mismatch' error at

```
brd = board_unit(1, 1)
```

[image]

How do I match the types here?

Comment: It's excel vb. I just realised that board_unit is not 2 elements although SMT_DOE_Unique_Board_Unit  is 2D Array.

Comment: Also `ArrayList` is not an Object in VBA.